# Shared memory between 2 processes (applications)

Tags: .net, memory, ipc, pipe, named-pipes

I can't find any useful answer for this question, although it has been asked in a different way several times.

I want to share a memory between two processes (two different applications),
so that one of them can write to that memory and the other can read.

Is this possible in .NET? How?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/439787/how-to-implement-shared-memory-in-net

Comment: But there is no good answer in that duplicated question too

Comment: There are good answers in the duplicated question. You just don't like what they say. But there is no build-in way to share memory in .NET, you can either use P-Invoke or try some other IPC.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted to hear, I was thinking that this is not possible in .NET currently (check my question) I just needed some someone to confirm that. thanks to you and nobugz and all the others.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Right now, .NET doesn't support sections (aka Memory Mapped Files).  It will soon, the 4.0 version has the System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles namespace.  There is a good reason it took so long and also the reason you are not going to be happy with this addition.  Using pointers is mandatory in MMFs, the shared memory is made available at a specific address.  To share a value, you'll have to write it to a specific address.

Pointers are however fundamentally incompatible with the managed memory model.  Objects are created in a garbage collected heap, the collector moves them around as needed to keep the heap compacted.  In a managed language, you have a reference to such an object, also knows as a "tracking handle".  The C/C++ equivalent is a pointer, but it is one with bells on, the garbage collector can always find it back and update its value.  The CLR does support the notion of "pinning", it converts a reference to a pointer.  It implements this by marking the object as unmoveable.  That however doesn't help implement shared memory through an MMF, the object is pinned in the GC heap instead of the virtual memory address where the MMF view is located.

To make an MMF work, the object needs to be copied from the GC heap to the shared memory.  That requires serialization.  The .NET 4.0 class is named MemoryMappedViewStream.  You probably can see where this is going, this is indistinguishable from using a named pipe or a socket.  Getting data in and out of an MMF takes the same amount of effort.  An MMF is merely slightly more efficient because the underlying buffer is not in the kernel memory pool.

You can break the rulez and do so today.  You can P/Invoke the CreateFileMapping, OpenFileMapping and MapViewOfFile you need to create an MMF.  And use the unsafe keyword so you can create pointers.  You'll need to use value types (like struct) for the shared memory elements or use the Marshal class.

Comment: You are assuming that "sharing data" must mean sharing managed objects directly. What if someone wants to share some "plain" data?

Comment: Not sure what "plain" means.  But you still can't affect the address of value types directly, they live on the stack or the GC heap.  A pointer is required to get them written to a MMF.

Comment: I think by plain data, he means just a bunch of bytes that you decipher yourself, he just wants to write the code to read/write the memory mapped file himself

Comment: Could you please comment on how up-to-date this answer is? Have there been improvements?

Comment: It is still up to date.

Answer (score 5):

**IPC**

If you are talking about Inter Process Communication. There are several possibilities like using tcp/udp sockets, mailslots, named pipes, memory mapped files, windows messages, etc.

.Net also offers some higher level IPC like [.Net remoting](http://www.beansoftware.com/NET-Tutorials/NET-Remoting-Tutorial.aspx) and [WCF](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/168490.aspx) which use the previous mentioned techniques. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56121/ipc-mechanisms-in-c-usage-and-best-practices).

**Memory Mapped Files**

If you really want to share a block of memory instead of communication then maybe memory mapped files are what you want. .Net 4.0 has [MemoryMappedFile](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/06/21/net-framework-4-0-using-memory-mapped-files.aspx) for that. If you don't or can't use .Net 4.0 you could implement it yourself as in this [win32 example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms810613.aspx). Or you could try [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/MemoryMappedGenericArray.aspx) code or see if you can use MemoryMappedFileStream mentioned [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446520.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998450.aspx). Or use this [FileMap](http://github.com/tomasr/filemap/) class.

Comment: I don't want to use named pipes, WCF, remoting ... etc ... that is why I specified "shared memory", shared memory between 2 Apps are easy to establish in c++, but I cant find a way to do it in C#.net

I am using .NET 2.0, is there anyway to solve this using it? I dont want to go throw 3rd parties

Answer (score 1):

Use a [named pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named_pipe#Named_pipes_in_Windows).

It's a mechanism that allows one process to write sequential data into a stream, from which the other process can read.

Note that named pipe only allow sequential read. If you need to use more elaborated queries, you might want to use client-server architecture. In this case, the reader process queries the other process for information using [network sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.aspx).

Comment: I don't want to use named pipes, WCF, remoting ... etc ... that is why I specified "shared memory", shared memory between 2 Apps are easy to establish in c++, but I cant find a way to do it in C#.net

Comment: I haven't seen any direct implementation of Shared memory, but you can easily implement a third process that would handle reads and writes of both processes using sockets.

Comment: I think everyone's missing the point. Sharing memory is fundamentally different to syncing objects through _any_ mechanism. With shared memory there is a consistent state shared between processes. With pipes/wcf/etc, there's a (de)serialise/transmit process which is expensive in terms of cycles. Shared memory is used when you want one process to manipulate an object in another directly (say how Chrome has multiple processes rendering into the same window. It's much cheaper to draw directly than serialize a bitmap over and over)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned use Memory Mapped Files.
Implementation for .NET <  4 available at: http://github.com/tomasr/filemap/
I have used and it works flawless. You may have some security issues when sharing between elevated/not elevated processes - the solution is to initialize the memory mapped file in the elevated process and set its security attributes accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The is an implementation , plus description at http://www.softwareinteractions.com/blog/2010/1/21/interprocess-communications-using-shared-memory.html