# C# Static memory address

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shared memory between 2 processes (applications)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004790/shared-memory-between-2-processes-applications)

Hello,

I need to store data into a particular fixed memory address because i need to read this data from another process.

So, every time I execute the program the address must remain the same.

Is there any way to do it?

thanks

Comment: Why can't you synchronize in files? Or communicate through sockets/queues?

Comment: Because one of the few things I can control in the process that's going to read the data is a memory address of my external process.

Comment: and the process who read is written in C, not using .net

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is duplicate, but I add Inter-process comunication can be easily solved using WCF + NamedPipes + SelfHosting

Comment: ok thanks, but i'd like to know if it's possible to allocate memory at some fixed address that would be the same address for every time i start the application on any machine