# Why is change to static field not propagated to another project/process in C#/.Net?

Tags: c#, static

I have a class (mydatarec) in my project (client) that is referenced to another project (server). When I call the public double (xxr) in the other project (server) I always get a zero value:

```
///client///
public class mydatarec
{
   public static double xxr;
}
.
.
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   mydatarec.xxr = 100;
          ...
}
```

In the other project:

```
///server///
//When I call it here..
Console.WriteLine(mydatarec.xxr); // I always get 0
```

I dont know how to continuously change the static double. I need your help!

Comment: Did you ensure that `Main` ran before you accessed the static field? If `Main` is part of a different application, it probably wasn't executed.

Comment: `Nice variable names by the way...` you should also get in the habit of creating variables that make sense and closely represent what it is you are trying to reference

Comment: Main runs before I call "mydatarec"

Comment: I will use different variable names. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You seem to assume that the value is shared by multiple processes. It's not. The static fields are shared only within one process (or more precisely within an appdomain).

If you actually need to share a memory between processes follow to question [Shared memory between 2 processes (applications)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2004790/850848).

Comment: how come when i do public static double xxr = 1; I get a value of 1 (not zero) in the other project. I think xxr is already shared but im gettnig the initial value only.

Comment: Because that new initial value is then set in both projects. So both start with 1. But that still does not make the value shared.