# Is it possible to access another process address space in order to reach a specific object instance?

Tags: c#, windows, com

I'm not sure if this question makes sense, but it has been pretty hard to find information so far.

My objective is to "attach" a process to another one that is already running. I'm not trying to debug either of them, I just want to access objects/context from the last.
I have read about `ICorDebug` interface, implemented an example with it (using `DebugActiveProcess()`) but couldn't simulate what i want to achieve.

My objective is to have a process running with a singleton instance in it and use this instance as a context in a second process (I have assemblies and type infos for both).

This is my first question here, be kind =)

Comment: have you looked into remoting the object, so it can be shared across multiple processes or even multiple workstations? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Remoting

Comment: It will not work in his scenario. It is too slow.

Comment: What sort of permissions will your process have?

Comment: @FrankThomas , I read(an tried today) about WCF, wich seems to be the follower of .net remote, but apperantly it does not expose the object, allowing only message passing through proxys, web-service like. Please correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: @Cameron, the processes have admin permissions and are intended to run locally in the same machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot access another processes address space.  That would be a huge security violation.  (In old windows and DOS you could).

Shared memory is one way to share data between processes: [How to implement shared memory in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439787/how-to-implement-shared-memory-in-net)